# I want to multithread raspberry pi spi0 and spi1

Tags: spi

I'm controlling two ssd1351 oleds in Raspberry Pi.
When I tested using one spi bus, I see the images on both screens differently. (One eye is closed first)

[image]

So, I wanted to threading another spi bus to transfer data at the same time. But even with other bus, there was confusion in communication.

[image]

The control used luma library. (https://github.com/rm-hull/luma.examples)
Please tell me why this is happening.

```
 import sys
 import time
 import os.path
 import threading
 from PIL import Image, ImageSequence
 from luma.core.sprite_system import framerate_regulator
 from luma.core.interface.serial import spi
 from luma.oled.device import ssd1351

 def main():
     global leye, reye

     regulator = framerate_regulator(fps=1000)
     img_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'image','eye_wink.gif'))
     eye_w = Image.open(img_path)

     size = [min(*L_eye.size)] * 2
     posn = ((L_eye.width - size[0]) // 2, L_eye.height - size[1])

     start=time.time()
     for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(eye_w):
         with regulator:
             l_eye = Image.new("RGB", L_eye.size, "white")
             l_eye.paste(frame.resize(size, resample=Image.LANCZOS), posn)
             leye.append(l_eye)
             r_eye = Image.new("RGB", R_eye.size, "white")
             r_eye.paste(frame.resize(size, resample=Image.LANCZOS), posn)
             reye.append(r_eye)
     print time.time()-start

     left=threading.Thread(target=trying_l)
     right=threading.Thread(target=trying_r)
     left.start()
     time.sleep(5)
     right.start()

 def trying_l():
     global leye
     l=len(leye)
     while True:
         print "wink"
         for i in range(l):
             L_eye.display(leye[i])
             print("left eye",i)
             time.sleep(0.1)

 def trying_r():
     global reye
     l=len(reye)
     while True:
         print "wink"
         for i in range(l):
             R_eye.display(reye[i])
             print("right eye",i)
             time.sleep(0.1)

 if __name__ == "__main__":
     leye=[]
     reye=[]
     try:
         L_eye = ssd1351(spi(port=0, device=0, gpio_RST=24, gpio_DC=25, bus_speed_hz=4000000), bgr=True)
         R_eye = ssd1351(spi(port=1, device=2, gpio_RST=6, gpio_DC=12, bus_speed_hz=4000000), bgr=True)
         while 1:
             main()
     except KeyboardInterrupt:
         pass
```

Comment: Have you looked at ssd1351?  Perhaps it has a variable common to the two threads which is clashing.

Comment: I did not check everything about ssd1351. However, when I changed the CS pins differently on the same spi bus, threads did not produce an error.